# Resize PDF books with a lot of code samples for smaller screens

Tags: pdf

I have a lot of pdf books about programming, but they are all in A4 format so it's really difficult to read them on my phone or ebook. I'm looking for a tool or a method that helps me to edit that pdfs so I can read them more comfortable.

All tools for pdf resizing I could find make the code blocks look really difficuilt to read.

Comment: There are PDF readers available that can reflow the page content for small screens. I suspect that is the easiest solution for you, then finding a tool, if you are just looking for your own personal solution. I would suggest checking the app store for your phone.

Comment: I also have old ebook without even internet access so it doesn't work for me

but thanks for the suggestion, if I don't find anything better I'll have to read from my phone)

Comment: btw I can't find any app that does it well

Comment: The company I work for has a showcase app, Xodo, available in all stores. Right now the Android version has PDF reflow support. PDF Reflow for iOS is in progress. Not sure about UWP Xodo. Not sure what platform your phone is. See my profile for link to Xodo.

Comment: sorry, but the books I read is even harder too read in this app. I think here is no good app for this thing, at least I haven't seen it (I tryed 15+ apps btw)

Comment: If you tried Xodo, and have feedback, there is a UserVoice page on Xodo site where you can give feedback to. But that is interesting to know that there was no good solution out there that you could find.